# How to Implement Map with Queue of objects

Tags: java, hashmap, queue, java.util.concurrent

I am little confused how to implement the following output,

```
{ 
     "finalOutput":{["test":{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
     "test1":{[],[],[]....[]},
     "test2":{[],[]....[]}]}
}
```

.

For this output, One Key should have 10 objects with Queue concepts.
For example key as `college : {[],[],[],[],[],[],[]..}`. Each key should not be more than 10 values. So i am thinking to implement with `ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Object>`. i dont know how to implement.

i am thinking with `MultivaluedMap` but i need to check each key has 10 or less objects. should not be more than 10 so need to check with FIFO policy.(If more than 10 need to remove first and insert the values.)

Can any one please suggest me how to implement. if any one has sample please help me.

Comment: Is it a json object ?

Comment: Yes , Json Object, but need to implemented with FIFO also so i confused how to implement.

Comment: by the JSON RFC: "An object is an unordered". If each '[]' (array) is element in your FIFO queue, then it's not gonna work. http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt

Answer (score -1):

You can design a map with values `BlockingQueue` whose size is 10 . If some where may cause not safe within concurrency , please tell me . I think it is OK .

```
Map<String,BlockingQueue<Object>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,BlockingQueue<Object>>(){
        @Override
        public BlockingQueue<Object> put(String key,
                BlockingQueue<Object> value) {
        BlockingQueue<Object> current = this.get(key);
        synchronized (current) {
            if(current.size() == 10){
            current.remove();
            }
            current.add(value.peek());
        }
            return super.put(key, current);
        }

        @Override
        public BlockingQueue<Object> get(Object key) {
        if(this.contains(key))
            return super.get(key);
        else
            return new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>(10);
        }
    };

    }
```

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but I guess Instead of BlockingQueue the ConcurrentLinkedDeque is better ? Bz ConcurrentLinkedDeque is support multithreading and thread safe.

Comment: 1. why overriding put/get?
2. this implementation will be contention point in multi-threaded environment, if performance is matters. avoid synchronized, and use better concurrent primitives the language offers you.
in this matter, just use 'compute' method of ConcurrentMap - the lock management is more right and you'll avoid this strange code.

Comment: @MichaelArenzon  overriding put/get to meet the requirements . Never should `synchronized` be used ?  Have you ever understand what  Dharmaraja.k what ?

Comment: @passion I have did. this is extremely bad practice extending concrete implementations, and even worse to override concrete data-structures. this override just ruined the whole idea of ConcurrentHashMap.
as I said before, this whole piece of code can be simply replaced with the atomic operations that 'ConcurrentMap' provides you, and being specific just using the method 'compute'.

Comment: @MichaelArenzon  concurrentmap has a method called compute ?

Comment: @passion http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-

Comment: @MichaelArenzon  I'm using jdk1.7 . And I don't think  it is extremely bad practice extending concrete implementations , it is the same as to extends it , and override some methods , and what do you mean by "ruined the whole idea of ConcurrentHashMap"  , I just override set/get , it has nothing to do with "data-structures" !

Comment: @passion About ruining the whole idea of ConucrrentHashMap - please read how its implemented. One interesting thing about ConcurrentHashMap, comparing to Hashtable (which is the synchronized version of HashMap) - is that the locks are based on buckets, rather than on the whole collection. Overriding 'put' with synchronized, kills this feature. Plus, as I said before, this is -bad- design code. One should not extend implementations, and -especially- not data-structures like that. I saw so many bad code ruining data-structures by extending, causing production errors. jdk7 - 'putIfAbsent'

Comment: @MichaelArenzon  I knew it . ConcurrentHashMap locks one segment , but I need to lock the value cause I need add and remove operations atomic , but when put into the map , uses its method . I don't think it destory something at all .